# Get timeInterval between keyDown & keyUp then store in object

Tags: javascript, rxjs, keyevent

I want to get the timeInterval between keydown and keyup events for a each key pressed

```
var down = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keydown")
    .filter(e => !e.repeat)

var up = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keyup");

var actions = {}
var keyPress = down.merge(up)
           .groupBy(e => e.keyCode)
        //Ideally, get timeInterval here
           .mergeAll()
           .do(actions[e.key].push(e.timeInterval))
```

I want structure the actions object like this

```
actions = {
           'w': {0: 1000ms, 1: 1123ms},
           'd': {0: 402ms}
          }
```

Haalp please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const keyDown$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keydown")
  .filter(e => !e.repeat)

const keyUp$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keyup");

keyDown$
  .mergeMap(keyDown => // For every key down we start a new observable, waiting for the-same-key up event
    keyUp$.filter(keyUp => keyUp.keyCode === keyDown.keyCode)
    .take(1)
    .map(keyUp => ({
      keyCode: keyUp.keyCode,
      key: keyUp.key,
      duration: keyUp.timeStamp - keyDown.timeStamp
    }))
  )
  .scan((actions, action) => { // The scan collects all the actions aggregated in a map by key. It emits the current aggregated map for every action
    actions[action.key] = actions[action.key] || {};
    const actionIndex = Object.keys(actions[action.key]).length;
    actions[action.key][actionIndex] = `${Math.round(action.duration)}ms`;
    return actions;
  }, {})
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks mate. 

Would you mind comment the lines so i can get better understanding of how this works, particularly in the mergeMap and scan.

Answer (score 0):

Variable for start time, then variable for difference, and format. Rinse and repeat, you can drop it in your own custom function to run on keydown/keyup or whatever, then just create and format the data into the object like how you want.

```
var startTime = Date.now();
var elapsedTime = ((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
```

Comment: not really what im looking for but thanks for the response